# Lighttpd restart and force-reload commands

Tags: lighttpd

What is the difference between the following

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/lighttpd force-reload
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my platform (ubutnu), I found that they are the same. Just looked the file and found:

```
case "$1" in

.... processing other options

;;
restart|force-reload)
  processing restart and force-reload options
```

For other services, it might be different.

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 this seems to have changed. `/etc/init.d/lighttpd` contains a separate `reload|force-reload` command.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be achieved using Signals. See the Blogpost about [Lighty's Angel](http://blog.lighttpd.net/articles/2007/09/02/there-is-an-angel-for-lighty) for an overview of the Signals supported by lighttpd.

In short

- SIGHUP leads to a graceful restart (config reloads)
- SIGINT is graceful shutdown as now
- all unhandled signals lead to a restart of the lighttpd process

The debian [Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-writing-init) also explains the different parameters:

- `start`
  start the service,
- `stop`
  stop the service,
- `restart`
  stop and restart the service if it's already running, otherwise start the service
- `reload`
  cause the configuration of the service to be reloaded without actually stopping and restarting the service,
- `force-reload`
  cause the configuration to be reloaded if the service supports this, otherwise restart the service.